# Error. Cannot assign because it is a method group

Tags: c#, methods, calculator

```
Static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double x;
        double y;
        char symbol;
        Console.WriteLine("First number: ");
        x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Second number: ");
        y = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("+ or - or * or / ?: ");
        symbol = (char)Console.Read();
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("First number = {0,0:f} \nSecond number = {1,0:f} \nResult = {2,0:f}", x, y, answer(x, y, symbol));
    }
    static double answer(double a, double b, char simb)
    {

        if (simb == '+')
           answer = a + b;
        else
            if (simb == '-')
               answer = a - b;
            else
                if (simb == '*')
                    answer = a * b;
                else
                    if (simb == '/')
                      answer = a / b;
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Error");
```

I am doing project for my class. It's a little calculator, where you put in first number, than second and then choose a + - * or /. Unfortunately there is an error witch i don't know how to fix. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want to do in `answer` method is

```
if (simb == '+')
       return a + b;
....
```

Like described you are returning a value from a function.
You cannot assign a value to a method.

In Pascal nevertheless it was a valid way how to return a value from function if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Umm, i was following an example in my book, that's why i did it that way. Here you can take a look at it [link]http://prntscr.com/8fwm6a , it's not in english but i think u'll get the point.

Comment: @Deividas: Mind the case of the letters. there is `suma` and `Suma` in the link... one is the name of a variable and the second is the name of a method. C# is a case-*sensitive* language

Comment: Thank you mate, now i see that.

Answer (score 1):

In C# the return value is not set by assigning it to the method name, it's set using the `return` keyword.

You can create a local variable for the return value. This gives a single exit point for the method, which is clearer in some cases:

```
static double answer(double a, double b, char simb) {
  double result;
  if (simb == '+') {
    result = a + b;
  } else if (simb == '-') {
    result = a - b;
  } else if (simb == '*') {
    result = a * b;
  } else if (simb == '/') {
    result = a / b;
  } else {
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
    result = 0;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Or you can return the value directy. Note that you will exit the method immediately by using `return`:

```
static double answer(double a, double b, char simb) {
  if (simb == '+') {
    return a + b;
  }
  if (simb == '-') {
    return a - b;
  }
  if (simb == '*') {
    return a * b;
  }
  if (simb == '/') {
    return a / b;
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Error");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the (old) Basic language you return a value from a function by assigning it to the function name. In C# you use the return statement. Note that the return statement terminates the method immediately, therefore you don't need the else-cases any more.

```
static double answer(double a, double b, char simb)
{
    if (simb == '+') return a + b;
    if (simb == '-') return a - b;
    if (simb == '*') return a * b;
    if (simb == '/') return a / b;
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
    return 0; // There must be a return statement in non-void methods.
}
```

However, I'm suggesting to use the switch statement, instead of long if-chains

```
static double answer(double a, double b, char simb)
{
    switch (simb) {
        case '+':
            return a + b;
        case '-':
            return a - b;
        case '*':
            return a * b;
        case '/':
        case ':':
            return a / b;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
            return 0;
    }
}
```